# Is there anything I can do if I found someone ripping off my content?

Tags: google, duplicate-content, content

I have created some content with very hard work (more than thousands of hours). And I found a website is just using all my content and put Google AdSense on it to generate money and traffic with my content.

What can I do to force him to stop? All the data are personal created so I don't have any "license" or official copyright.

Will Google be able to help? I have detailed and solid evidence.

Any tips for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can file a DMCA complaint with Google to have it removed from the search results, you don't have to have 'official copyright', if it is your content then the copyright is yours in any case.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dmca-notice?rd=1&pli=1

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the U.S. you can hire an attorney and send a cease and desist notice. Give them ten days to respond, then file a Federal law suit. Nothing speaks louder than a Federal law suit. Your content will not only be taken down, but they will be extremely eager to settle before going to court.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not in the US.

Comment: Some countries have similar enough laws that I would check into what you can do. Fortunately for us in the U.S., the copyright laws are strong. I hope that the laws are strong for you too.